# Mercurial Loop error followed by locks on commit. Mercurial/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

Error and eclipse info below.   Basically I clone a repository, change one file and commit.  The commit screen flashes I see the error in the log and when I go  and try to commit again I get lock timeouts.  I've cleared the locks and recovered the repository but always the locks.   Anyone been through this and fixed it before?

Thanks
   Bill

MercurialEclipse 2.2

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product -data file:/C:/dev/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product

Java.lang.IllegalStateException: cmdserver is still executing request
                at com.aragost.javahg.internals.AbstractCommand.getReturnCode(AbstractCommand.java:325)
                at com.aragost.javahg.commands.CommitCommand.doExecute(CommitCommand.java:90)
                at com.aragost.javahg.commands.CommitCommand.execute(CommitCommand.java:73)
                at com.aragost.javahg.commands.CommitCommand.execute(CommitCommand.java:108)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgCommitClient.commit(HgCommitClient.java:121)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgCommitClient.commitResources(HgCommitClient.java:70)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.dialogs.CommitDialog.performCommit(CommitDialog.java:667)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.dialogs.CommitDialog.okPressed(CommitDialog.java:462)
                at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)
                at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
                at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
                at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.menu.CommitHandler.run(CommitHandler.java:56)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.ActionCommit.doRun(ActionCommit.java:64)
                at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.ActionCommit.run(ActionCommit.java:47)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
                at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
                at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
                at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
                at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
                at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
                at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
                at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
                at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
                at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: I am the maintainer of both MercurialEclipse and JavaHg. Before anything, you are running version 2.2, which is **no longer supported**. I suggest you update as I see no reason not to. The error you are facing may be due a variety of reasons, including to the way that interaction with Hg must be handled: JavaHg interprets strings output by the Mercurial command server and any changes in any string is likely to cause errors.

Comment: It's running the 2.3 Jar.  I looked into it.   These were fresh installs from the marketplace.   I havn't tried yet installing through the web but I can give it a shot.

Comment: Then all is fine. You should create an issue on the BitBucket repository and I'll look into it. Your hg version will be useful, as well as the list of extensions that are enabled (we recently discovered that extensions could get in the way of JavaHg). FYI, the next version (2.4) is scheduled for early October.

Comment: AnyEdit Tools 2/7.0
AppLaug PhoneGap for Android JSLint/JSHint 1.2
Eclipse CKEditor 1.0.1
Eclipse Java Dev. Tools 4.5
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.7.2
Eclipse-pmd 1.10
Enide Studio 0.5.33
JSHint Eclipse 0.10
Mylyn 3.23
Subversive 4.0.5  adding as a reference.  Installed extensions.

Comment: Bug submitted to MecurialEclipse bitbucket bugtracker.  https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issues/535/new-hgeclipse-install-get-a-loop-error

Comment: Mea culpa. I wasn't specific enough: I meant Mercurial extensions, the ones that are in your .hgrc file. Sorry that it could be understood as Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Updated with extensions.   Also included code for homegrown.

Comment: Looks like some local hooks caused the issue.  Commenting out the hooks in the .ini file worked.   We will debug those offline.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically some local hooks in the HG install with precommit checks caused this error.  Commenting out the HG add-ons solved the problem.